# The solution on how to wait for element to be visible in Shadow DOM

Tags: element, visibility, shadow-dom

Currently there is no out of box solution in the Robot Framework libraries on how to wait until the element is visible on the page in shadow DOM. I came up with one approach. Perhaps it will be useful for others.

I created a keyword:

```
Verify ShadowDom Element Visible
    [Arguments]    ${Element}
    register keyword to run on failure    Capture Page Screenshot
    ${previous_kw}=    register keyword to run on failure    Nothing
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    1    30
        sleep    1s
        ${status2}=    Run Keyword and return Status    execute javascript    return ${Element}.checkVisibility();
        IF    '${status2}'=='False'    CONTINUE
        ...    ELSE    BREAK
    END
    register keyword to run on failure    ${previous_kw}
    IF    '${status2}'=='False'    Capture Page Screenshot
    IF    '${status2}'=='False'    Fail    Element not visible after 30 sec.


Verify ShadowDom Element Visible      document.querySelector("xxxx-block-wizard-footer").shadowRoot.querySelector(".xxxx-block-wizard-footer__cta-primary").shadowRoot.querySelector("button")
```

In this case, we are expecting some button in shadow DOM to appear on the page within 30 seconds. If button did not appear, a screenshot would be captured and a fail message will be sent to log.

Note: If the button is visible, no screenshot is taken on all the failed attempts to verify.
Good luck.